# How do I install KDE nepomuk playground?

Tags: kde, kde-4, nepomuk

I'm particularly interested in using the fancybookmarking konqueror plugin of KDE nepomuk playground. I tried installing it in the standard way (giving the install prefix as /usr), then quitting and reopening konqueror, but konqueror couldn't see the new plugin in Extensions.

Answer (score 1):

My fancy bookmarking project has not been integrated with the master repo yet. So you can download it from 'fancybookmarking' branch of 'nepomukannotation' repo. 
After downloading the source code, simply build and install the 'nepomukannotation'.

I assume that you already have KDE development environment setup in your system. 
If you don't know how to pull the code here are the steps:

1. Clone nepomukannotation:
   `git clone git://anongit.kde.org/nepomukannotation.git`
2. Go into the nepomukannotation folder:
   `cd nepomukannotation`
3. Create a new branch called fancybookmarking:
   `git branch fancybookmarking`
4. Switch the branch to fancybookmarking:
   `git checkout fancybookmarking`
5. Pull the code:
   `git pull origin fancybookmarking`

After this step simply compile and install nepomukannotation.

If you have not setup KDE development environment , then you need to wait for some time. I'll integrate my plugin with the master repo asap. If you need any more clarification feel free to ask me.

Comment: Yes, this is essentially what I did. But I did not see the plugin in Konqueror after I installed it. Is there something I need to do to make konqueror detect the plugin?